# Help finding information on Marble coated woks

Tags: wok, stir-fry

I've been looking for a wok and was considering a carbon steel wok, but from my research, it seems that carbon steel woks, even if they have a flat bottom, may warp slightly from the heat and not remain flat.

Since I have a flat top cook surface, I'm not sure if one of these is right for me.

I have read about marble coated woks that are supposedly good for flat cook tops, but I can't find any detailed information on them.

Do they require any special care (e. g. seasoning) and are they good for stir frying at high temperatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could benefit from user experience by posting your question in the Customer Questions and Answers section of a product sold by Amazon.

For example, try posting here:

[http://www.amazon.com/Ceramic-Marble-Coated-Aluminium-inches/dp/B004FSS43I#Ask](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004FSS43I)

Comment: That's a good link. 17 reviews (interestingly 14 are 5 star and 3 are one star), and 8 answered questions as of 2/12/15.